# OS X - How to disable the opening file animation?

Tags: macos, finder, animation

Does anyone know of a way to disable this animation:

[image: open file animation]

I recall being able to in previous iterations of OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all animation in Finder with:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations -bool true && killall -HUP Finder
```

I don't recall a preference just for this animation though.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't disable it.

Comment: @user46751 Which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: OS X version 10.9.3